# @media (orientation: portrait) not detecting change in browser window

Tags: media-queries

I've written code as follows:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">     
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The "test.css" file reads likewise:

```
body { 
  background-image: url("home-bg-slow-alt.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    background-size: 100vw auto;        
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    background-size: auto 100vh;    
  }
}
```

But whenever I view the html file, the portrait orientation query never takes effect on desktop, no matter which browser I use, or how thin I make the window.

I know "background-size: cover" is supposed to keep the image's aspect ratio and constantly cover the entirety of the page, but for some reason this method displays oddly on certain mobile browsers.

Is there a way to run a media query based on the viewport width compared to the height?  I believe that the orientation method is literally detecting the size of my screen, and not the actual size of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Add `screen` to your media query and it should work.

`@media screen and (...`